# Playing an audio file

Tags: html5-audio, clojurescript, web-audio-api

I'm looking for a basic example for playing an .mp3 or .wav file in the browser. Ideally, also for playing multiple files at overlapping times.

Most libraries I found are concerned with sound synthesis and their examples focus on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [cljs-bach](https://github.com/ctford/cljs-bach), a wrapper around the [Web Audio API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/). It's easier than to use than [HTML5 Audio](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp), since it enables the playback of multiple audio buffers at the same time without the need to create multiple DOM nodes.

Here's the kind of example I was looking for:

```clj
(ns foo.bar (:require [cljs-bach.synthesis :as b]))

(defonce audio-context (b/audio-context))

(defn playback-mp3
  [url]
  (let [mp3 (b/connect-> (b/sample url)  ; read file using js ajax, including caching
                         (b/gain 0.5)    ; you can chain optional effects here
                         b/destination)  ; loudspeakers
        ]
    (b/run-with mp3
                audio-context
                (b/current-time audio-context) 
                3.0  ; play for 3 seconds
     )))

; (playback-mp3 "/music/qux.mp3")
```